# Python crashes using PyQt4 in a for loop

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, pyqt4

What I got so far is code working for one single page but I want it to work for several pages(7*29 in a loop) e.g.
http://www.oddsportal.com/basketball/usa/nba-2013-2014/results/#/page/1
I'm guessing, that somehow you have to restart the browser simulation everytime but I'm not exactly sure, how. 
So this is the console output I get running the code(python 3.5).

```
content-type missing in HTTP POST, defaulting to application/x-www-form-   urlencoded. Use QNetworkRequest::setHeader() to fix this problem.
done
QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::configurationAdded(QNetworkConfiguration) to QNetworkConfigurationManager::configurationAdded(QNetworkConfiguration)
QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::configurationRemoved(QNetworkConfiguration) to QNetworkConfigurationManager::configurationRemoved(QNetworkConfiguration)
QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::configurationChanged(QNetworkConfiguration) to QNetworkConfigurationManager::configurationChanged(QNetworkConfiguration)
QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::onlineStateChanged(bool) to QNetworkConfigurationManager::onlineStateChanged(bool)
QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::configurationUpdateComplete() to QNetworkConfigurationManager::updateCompleted()
```

I'm also not sure, what the content-type missing is, but it works for a single page just fine, so I ignored it.
To test the stuff I want to do with it, I went ahead and changed the url manually for the 2014 season and it turned out to work fine, so I'm kinda lost. 
the code consists of a generic scraping javascript part that I pretty much copy pasted and a html interpreting part I wrote myself. 
Since im not sure, where the problem is, here is the complete code.

```
from lxml import html
import sys  
from PyQt4.QtGui import *  
from PyQt4.QtCore import *  
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import * 
import pickle
```

#### javascript scraping according to google, with first rendering the page and then loading it to html

```
class Render(QWebPage):
    def __init__ (self,url):
        self.app =QApplication(sys.argv)
        QWebPage.__init__(self)
        self.loadFinished.connect(self._loadFinished)
        self.mainFrame().load(QUrl(url))
        self.app.exec_()

    def _loadFinished(self, result):
        self.frame = self.mainFrame()
        self.app.quit()


def getHtml(str_url):
    r_html = Render(str_url)  
    html = r_html.frame.toHtml()
    return html


def is_number(s):
    try:
        float(s)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

## this method incorporates the standard lxml procedure and the javascript rendering to get the games and odds of a particular page for further processing and put it in a list

```
def scrape_js(url):
    str_html = getHtml(url)
    result = str(str_html.encode("utf-8"))
    tree = html.fromstring(result)
    content = tree.xpath('//table[@class=" table-main"]//tr[(@class="  deactivate") or (@class="odd deactivate")]//td[position()>1]//text()')
    liste=[[]]
    i=0;
    k=0;
    n=int(len(content))
    while i<n:
        if  is_number(content[i-1]) and is_number(content[i-2]) and is_number(content[i-3]):
            liste.append([content[i]])
            i+=1
            k+=1
        else:
            liste[k].append(content[i])
            i+=1

    liste = liste[1:]
    for line in liste:
        if is_number(line[2]):
            liste = liste[1:]

    return liste

complete_liste = []        
file_name = 'odds_2009'
```

## for the 2008/09 season, I'd like to get all 29 pages but after completing the first page, javascript crashes

```
for page in range(30):
    url = ''.join(['http://www.oddsportal.com/basketball/usa/nba-2008-2009/results/#/page/',str(page)])
    liste = scrape_js(url)
    for line in liste:
        complete_liste.append(line)
    print('done')

fileObject = open(file_name,'wb')
pickle.dump(complete_liste,fileObject)
fileObject.close()
```

Comment: could it be simply the space between years ?  `2008-   2009` if I remove the space the website loads fine.

Comment: oh. no. well the space seems to be the result of formatting on stackoverflow. Everything works fine for the first iteration of the loop but then after that it crashes if I interpret the console output correctly.